# Adding a rotating RGB border to a model

Tags: modeling, animation, lighting

I'm pretty new to blender but I have this model of a card which i've created. I want to add a rotating border similar to those you see with RGB mousemats. Does anyone know of a good way to implement this? I tried looking online but to no avail :(

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try something like this - it just rotates a radial gradient on the z axis and then colors it. Make sure to write *#frame* in the Value node to make it keep up with the current frame:

[image: Frame]

Final result looks like this (less choppy actually, I had to cut some off for the gif):

[image: Frame2]

Comment: This is a great solution and yet so simple. Thanks.